# Syntax error in function but everything seems correct

Tags: python-3.x

I am custom defining a function and following is my function but I get error as below

```
def  saveSlice(img, fname, path):
     img  = np.uint8(img * 255)
     fout = os.path.join(path, f'{fname}.png')
     cv2.imwrite(fout, img)
     print(f'[+] Slice saved: {fout}', end='\r')
```

I get error message as below

File "ipython-input-79-e8d731623c8b", line 3
fout = os.path.join(path, f'{fname}.png')

```
                                                                           ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Python earlier than 3.6 `f-strings` are not available, and that code has an incorrect syntax. In that case you can use the `format` method of the strings instead like that (2 lines are modified):

```py
def  saveSlice(img, fname, path):
     img  = np.uint8(img * 255)
     fout = os.path.join(path, '{}.png'.format(fname))
     cv2.imwrite(fout, img)
     print('[+] Slice saved: {}'.format(fout), end='\r')
```

Comment: Excellent and thanks. The code worked but only the last line single = has to be changed to == i.e.  end == '\r'

Comment: So you use Python 2.x? You shouldn't. In 2.x print is not a function but a command. You can write `print '[+] Slice saved: {}'.format(fout)` then. Or better. Use `from __future__ import print_function` at the beginning of the file/notebook

Comment: I use 3.6.9 version of python

Comment: Then f-strings should work.